# PHP compare two XML files with result in both of XML

Tags: php, xml, comparison

I want to compare two unknown XML files with the same structure in php. I'm new with XML (not php) and therefore I'm having a little trouble with that. I found a lot of example code but I was not able to port the code to my problem.
my Problem:

here are two example XML file

xml1:

```
<start>
 <eins>
     <zwei>
        <drei>test1</drei>
        <vier>test2</vier>
        <fuenf>test3</fuenf>
     </zwei>
     <sechs>
        <sieben>
            <acht>test4</acht>
            <neun>tets5</neun>
        </sieben>
     </sechs>
    </eins> 
</start>
```

xml2:

```
<start>
 <eins>
    <zwei>
        <fuenf>test3</fuenf>
        <zehn>hmm</zehn>
        <drei>testFail</drei>
    </zwei>
    <sechs>
        <sieben>
            <neun>tets5</neun>
            <acht>test3</acht>
        </sieben>
    </sechs>
 </eins>        
</start>
```

Now I want to compare both of them and want back two xml files with the same order of nodes and with shows me the missing once.

output newXML1:

```
<start>
 <eins>
     <zwei>
        <drei>test1</drei>
        <vier>test2</vier>
        <fuenf>test3</fuenf>
        <missing>missing</missing>
     </zwei>
     <sechs>
        <sieben>
            <acht>test4</acht>
            <neun>tets5</neun>
        </sieben>
     </sechs>
    </eins> 
</start>
```

output newXML2:

```
<start>
 <eins>
    <zwei>
        <drei>testFail</drei>
        <missing>missing</missing>
        <fuenf>test3</fuenf>
        <zehn>hmm</zehn>
    </zwei>
    <sechs>
        <sieben>
            <acht>test3</acht>
            <neun>tets5</neun>
        </sieben>
    </sechs>
 </eins>        
</start>
```

In the output XML I want two have the same order of nodes and I want to see which element is missing. The outcome of the exercise is to use it to visualize the differences of two xml files on a html page. Many thanks for your help. :-)

@LMC you have ask for my current code. Here it is:

```
function checkXML($xml, $xml2, &$xmlNew, &$nodeCount) {
    foreach($xml as $key => $xmlpos) {
        if (isset($xml2->$key))
        {
           if($xmlpos->count())
            {
                xmlwriter_start_element($xmlNew,$key);
                $nodeCount = $xmlpos->count();
                checkXML($xmlpos, $xml2->$key, $xmlNew, $nodeCount);
                $nodeCount--;
            }
            else
            {
              xmlwriter_write_element($xmlNew,$key,$xml2->$key);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //echo $key . " - this is missing";
            xmlwriter_write_element($xmlNew,"missing","missing");
        }
    }
    xmlwriter_end_document($xmlNew);
}

$xmlStr1 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<start>
 <eins>
     <zwei>
        <drei>test1</drei>
        <vier>test2</vier>
        <fuenf>test3</fuenf>
     </zwei>
     <sechs>
        <sieben>
            <acht>test4</acht>
            <neun>tets5</neun>
        </sieben>
     </sechs>
    </eins> 
</start>';

$xmlStr2 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<start>
 <eins>
    <zwei>
        <fuenf>test3</fuenf>
        <zehn>hmm</zehn>
        <drei>testFail</drei>
    </zwei>
    <sechs>
        <sieben>
            <neun>tets5</neun>
            <acht>test3</acht>
        </sieben>
    </sechs>
 </eins>        
</start>';

$xml1 = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr1);
$xml2 = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr2);

$newXML = xmlwriter_open_memory();
xmlwriter_start_document($newXML,"1.0");

$nodeCount[0] = 0;
checkXML($xml1, $xml2, $newXML, $nodeCount);

//Header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo "<xmp>";
$xml_data=xmlwriter_output_memory($newXML);
echo $xml_data;
echo "</xmp>";

output:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<eins>
  <zwei>
    <drei>testFail</drei>
    <missing>missing</missing>
    <fuenf>test3</fuenf>
  </zwei>
</eins>
<sechs>
  <sieben>
    <acht>test3</acht>
    <neun>tets5</neun>
  </sieben>
</sechs>
```

This code is nearly what I wanted. Now I have the problem that I have to remember which node have to close at the right position. The node `<eins>` is closing too early currently.

Comment: What's the php code you tried so far? Questions are encouraged to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @LMC
I have put my current code to my question. I still have a problem with closing the nodes correctly.